# JQuery checking when element is in Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I've tried a dozen libraries to achieve this effect but I must be making a mistake somewhere. I'm currently using this library:- [zeusdeux/isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport).

In my css I have a style called .animated-element like so:-

```
.animation-element {
}
.in-view {
}
```

and I have several css elements that start an animation when the .in-view class is added:-

```
.trans-1 {
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s; 
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In my html I have div elements with these classes for animating:-

```
<div class="fade trans-1 animation-element">
                <h2 class="medium-subheader-bold">Header</h2>
</div>
```

Finally, the javascript checks whether an element is in the viewport using the library, and adds a class to the element if it is. Thereby changing the .fade to .fade.in-view (opacity 0 to 1):-

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('.animation-element').removeClass('in-view');
            $('.animation-element:in-viewport').addClass('in-view');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

When I load the page in a browser, all the elements in the page are loaded immediately and animated. When I inspect the webpage to check elements that are not visible in the viewport, I can see that they are rapidly flickering between adding and removing the in-view class. I've also tried removing the `$('.animation-element').removeClass('in-view');` line from the above javascript but the in-view class is still added immediately, even though elements are far out of the viewport.

I've tried this with several libraries and keep running into the same problem, so it must be the way I'm implementing it and not the fault of the library.

I should also say I'm using Pug to generate the html, regular css, and serving whole pages through node.js.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces issue

Comment: sounds like it might be the considered scope of the 'viewport', can you get the height of the viewport `console.log( $(window).height() );` perhaps and compare that with the top position of your divs `console.log( $'.animation-element').position().top );` ? maybe also define `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }` in your CSS so you're not inadvertently measuring the full scope of your html.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the issue was. I spent a whole day trying to recreate it in JSFiddle and modifying different parts. In the end it was because I didn't put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html document. Its crazy that everything else worked, even the animations when scrolling up, just not scrolling down, because of that one line.